# What this line means in Apex? "upsert engagements RelatedRecordID__c"

Tags: apex, soql, sql

I have this line in Apex:

> upsert engagements RelatedRecordID__c

What this line means?

It means that it upsert only field values of **RelatedRecordID__c** to **engagements** records? (and it doesn't update any other fields?)

Comment: This one can help -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm 
Also check comment at line 24 of latest example

Answer (score 5):

> To determine whether a record already exists, the upsert statement or Database method uses the record’s ID as the key to match records, **a custom external ID field**, or a standard field with the idLookup attribute set to true.

What is means?

Let's assume that there is a record with `RelatedRecordID__c = '1234'`.

```
//Existing record

new YourRecord(
    Name = 'Test',
    RelatedRecordID__c = '1234'
);
```

When you try to:

```
YourRecord newRecord = new YourRecord(
    Name = 'Test Update',
    RelatedRecordID__c = '1234'
);
upsert newRecord RelatedRecordID__c;
```

You will update existing record based on `RelatedRecordID__c`.